# How to treat day values in monthly data for use in RClimDex

Tags: r

I have CRU monthly station data that I would like to feed into RClimDex for index calculation. But since the day values are mostly missing, the software won't pick the data up.
Does anyone know how to handle the Day values?
The data looks like below.

2011 01 16 0.0000 -1.1095 -10.4922
2011 01 16 0.0306 -2.5678 -11.8757
2011 01 16 0.0000 -5.6643 -13.6188
2011 01 16 0.0000 -5.9002 -7.1169
2011 01 16 0.0000 1.2454 -8.6810

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the complete code and library statements that reproduces the problem.

Comment: There is no code. Feeding the data for quality control is rather the first step, at which I am stuck. The only libraries used are `climdex.pcic`. I'm I missing something?